What index can be created to optimise this query?
I've got the below SQL query that runs extremely slowly. As for this query, this is due to the "ORDER BY" statement, since Postgres is scanning the changes table by "counter" which can have millions of values. Removing the "ORDER BY" statement makes the query fast.
For the other query mentioned above, I optimised it by creating an index on two fields. For this query however I'm not sure what index would be the right one. I tried with an index on (item_id, counter) but it didn't help at all, and I don't know what else I could try. Any suggestions?
Slow SQL query:
SELECT "id", "item_id", "item_name", "type", "updated_time", "counter"
FROM "changes"
WHERE counter > -1
AND type = 2
AND item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM user_items WHERE user_id = 'xxxx')
ORDER BY "counter" ASC
LIMIT 200;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) result:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1001.15..27628.99 rows=200 width=99) (actual time=98730.912..116273.818 rows=200 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=78113369 read=3224064 dirtied=3
   I/O Timings: read=137436.119
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.15..10431526.45 rows=78343 width=99) (actual time=98730.911..116273.783 rows=200 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=78113369 read=3224064 dirtied=3
         I/O Timings: read=137436.119
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..10421483.70 rows=32643 width=99) (actual time=98493.185..112919.559 rows=75 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=78113369 read=3224064 dirtied=3
               I/O Timings: read=137436.119
               ->  Parallel Index Scan using changes_pkey on changes  (cost=0.56..5949383.56 rows=6197986 width=99) (actual time=1.076..42523.117 rows=4075591 loops=3)
                     Index Cond: (counter > '-1'::integer)
                     Filter: (type = 2)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 10370914
                     Buffers: shared hit=18993521 read=2672415
                     I/O Timings: read=85551.814
               ->  Index Scan using user_items_item_id_index on user_items  (cost=0.56..0.72 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=0 loops=12226772)
                     Index Cond: ((item_id)::text = (changes.item_id)::text)
                     Filter: ((user_id)::text = 'xxxx'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                     Buffers: shared hit=59119848 read=551649 dirtied=3
                     I/O Timings: read=51884.305
 Settings: effective_cache_size = '16179496kB', jit = 'off', work_mem = '100000kB'
 Planning Time: 1.465 ms
 Execution Time: 116273.929 ms
(26 rows)

Indexes:
"changes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (counter)
"changes_id_index" btree (id)
"changes_id_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
"changes_item_id_index" btree (item_id)
"changes_user_id_counter_index" btree (user_id, counter)
"changes_user_id_index" btree (user_id)


Please provide EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output.

also provide some information about indexes you have see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions

@LaurenzAlbe, I have added the full EXPLAIN output now

@nbk, I have also added the indexes

What version of PostgreSQL?

@jjanes, it's 12.17. Are there optimisations I can apply depending on the Postgres version?

Yes, the planner changes from version to version, both how it costs things and in what options are available to it.  But I ask because I can't reproduce this, I get a hash join.  I don't know if it is version specific behavior or because I don't have your actual data to work with.

The cause of the problem is the following: The optimizer thinks that there are enough rows in changes that are related to a user_items row with the correct user_id that it can quickly find 100 results by scanning changes in counter order and discarding rows that don't satisfy the condition until it has found 100 results and is done. However, it has to scan 10371014 rows until it has enough results, which takes very long. The cause might well be that all matching changes have rather high counter values.
There is very little you can do about that:

You can speed up the inner index scan as much as possible, like the other answers suggest.

You can change the ORDER BY so that PostgreSQL cannot use its preferred strategy:
ORDER BY counter + 0

Perhaps the resulting execution plan is faster.



Thank you, after trying all solutions mentioned here the counter + 0 tweak is the only one that made a difference - it went from 2 minutes to 6 seconds. A bit of a weird trick but that definitely helps.

@laurent It might be interesting to figure out why the tweak is needed. One explanation could be that most of the qualifying rows are at the wrong end of the "counter" range--there is nothing that can be done about that except resorting to hacks like this one.  The other possibility is that your row estimates are way off. To assess that, we would need to see an EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the query in which the LIMIT was omitted. The problem is that with the current plan, it stops counting rows when the plan stops running so we don't know many there would have been.

you shold rewrite your query to
SELECT "id", c."item_id", "item_name", "type", "updated_time", "counter"
FROM "changes" c JOIN (SELECT item_id FROM user_items WHERE user_id = 'xxxx') ui
ON c.item_id = ui.item_id
WHERE counter > -1
AND type = 2
ORDER BY "counter" ASC
LIMIT 200;

With the indexes
  changes (type, item_id, counter) INCLUDE (id, item_name, updated_time)
  user_items (user_id)

that should gove the query some  speed
The join is usually faster as the IN a
a combined index for chnages that include the three column in the ON and WHERE clause should incease alone the speed.
the same goes for user_item where the user should also have an index if it hasn't already one

It looks like the following indexes would work for you.
The idea is to add first the equality predicates, then the join/sorting/inequality predicates, then add other columns as INCLUDE.
changes (type, counter) INCLUDE (id, item_id, item_name, updated_time)
user_items (user_id, item_id)

Another option, depending on the cardinality of the join (how many rows)
changes (type, item_id, counter) INCLUDE (id, item_name, updated_time)


Thanks for your answer. I'm not very familiar with these types of indexes. I guess it means I'll need to change them if I ever change the fields in the SELECT statement?
